# How do I set bash environment variables from a script?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have some proxy settings that I only occasionally want to turn on, so I don't want to put them in my `~/.bash_profile`. I tried putting them directly in `~/bin/set_proxy_env.sh`, adding `~/bin` to my `PATH`, and `chmod +x`ing the script but though the script runs, the variables don't stick in my shell. Does anyone know how to get them to stick around for the rest of the shell session?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use one of:

```
source <file>

. <file>
```

Comment: that sir, is money in the bank

Answer (score 23):

In the script use

`export varname=value`

and also execute the script with:

`source set_proxy_env.sh`.

The `export` keyword ensures the variable is marked for automatic inclusion in the environment of subsequently executed commands.  Using `source` to execute a script starts it with the present shell instead of launching a temporary one for the script.

Comment: I had the `export`; it was the `source` I was missing.

Answer (score 8):

Did you try this:

`. ~/bin/set_proxy_env.sh`

Running it by itself opens a separate subshell (I think) and sets the variable there. But then the binding is lost after exiting back into your shell. The dot at the front tells it to run it within the same shell.

Also, don't forget to `export` the variables you need like so: `export MYVAR=value`

Comment: It's not necessary to export every variable. Only the ones you need to be visible to child processes.

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I meant :)